# Did not understand C++ stack<char*> behavior

Tags: c++, std, stdstack

I got stuck for two hours trying to understand what is happening in this simple C++ test program, but still did not get it. It should just receive three strings as inputs, insert them into a stack and finally print all elements of this same stack.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    stack<char*> stk;
    
    int stringLength;
    
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        char new_element[200];
        scanf("%s", new_element);
        stringLength = strlen(new_element);
        stk.push(new_element);
    }
    
    cout << "Stack content: ";
    while(!stk.empty()){
        cout << stk.top() << " ";
        stk.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;

}
```

The strange thing is that the final output is the same element (the last one added) printed 3 times, which makes no sense to me.

For example, if the inputs are:

```
John
Mary
Rick
```

then the current output is

```
Rick
Rick
Rick
```

Can anyone help me understanding and fixing this?

Comment: new_element is out of scope by the time you access it, invoking UB.

Comment: Note: You don't have an array of strings, you have an array of char pointers.

Comment: you are thinking `char *` as an equivalent of string, in reality, they are just `char pointers` (so they only hold addresses). you are pushing the same address that the `new_element` had in the stack. And latter invoking undefined behavior by dereferencing them to print (their address are out of scope by then). UB lets the compiler do whatever they like, and in your case, even the address was out of scope, the address held the last value you entered. Hence, printing the same values.
Either use different pointers by using `strdup` (that duplicates and returns a new pointer) or use `string`.

Answer (score 5):

```
    char new_element[200];
    // [...]
    stk.push(new_element);
```

You're pushing the same pointer in your stack object.

What's worse is, you're pushing system stack pointers, so if you were to use the stack from outside your function, you'd get an access violation (segfault in Linux) and crash. In your case you aren't using them from outside though, since the stack object is also on the stack.

Anyway, there's two quick fixes:

1. Write proper code: use `string` and let the compiler figure out copying them around and cleaning them up as needed.
2. Don't write proper code: use `strdup` to get an unique string pointer. You may or may not want to free them at some point, that always seems optional for people opting for this route.

Comment: Sure there are, there's virtual memory pointers! I'll remove it though to reduce confusion.

Comment: also there is no "system" stack, just the stack.

Comment: Whether or not using `char*` strings and `strdup` in C++ code is *improper* is subject to debate. However, not using `free()` when finished is, IMHO, most certainly *improper*. Nice answer, though!

Comment: @user253751 I think the point is to distinguish between the program's stack and the user's `std::stack`.

Comment: @AdrianMole freeing stuff at the end of a program is actually optional. There are reasons why you should, but also, it's incorrect to say that you must.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have declared `stk` as a `std::stack<char*>`, its elements will be `char*`, or *pointers* to `char` data (i.e. ***addresses***).

So, what you do when execute the `stk.push(new_element);` line is place the **address** of your (local) character array onto the stack. Technically, when you then `pop` that address later and print the string it points to, you are performing *undefined behaviour*, as the memory pointed to has gone out of scope (it's 'lifetime' is just one iteration of the first `for` loop).

However, your system simply re-uses the same address/buffer on each loop iteration, so your `scanf("%s", new_element);` line is replacing the contents of that buffer each time. Then, when you print the contents of the three stack elements, each of which will be the ***same*** address, you are simply displaying the last-modified version of that buffer.

To fix this, either use a `std::string` for your 'local' variable (which will then be *copied* by the `push` call); or, if you *insist* on using a `char*`, then push the address of a *copy* of that, made using the `strdup()` function:

```cpp
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        char new_element[200];
        scanf("%s", new_element);
        stringLength = strlen(new_element);
        stk.push(strdup(new_element)); // Allocate and copy the buffer before pushing
    }
```

Then, in your second loop, don't forget to release the memory when you're done with it:

```cpp
    while(!stk.empty()){
        cout << stk.top() << " ";
        free(stk.top()); // Release the allocated memory before we lose the pointer
        stk.pop();
    }
```

The `strdup()` and `free()` functions are declared in the `<stdlib.h>` header file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string` instead of `char*`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <cstring>

int main(){
    
    stack<string> stk;
    
    int stringLength;
    
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        string new_element;
        cin>>new_element;
        cout<<new_element<<"\n";
        stk.push(new_element);
    }
    
    cout << "Stack content: ";
    while(!stk.empty()){
        cout << stk.top() << " ";
        stk.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Good: recommendation to use `std:string` and demonstration.  Bad: `using namespace std;`. Overall: No up- or down-vote.

Comment: Not quite. You need either `using std::string` (and others) or to add the `std::` namespace prefix before each use of an STL class. See here: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073)